# What affects Blackjack gameplay in Fallout: New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

What specifics do we know, if any, about the blackjack implementation in Fallout New Vegas? Specifically:

- How does luck modify the game? (Does it modify the odds of you getting a card you need, one which won't bust you, etc.? Does it modify the odds of the dealer pulling a bust card, etc.?)
- Do we know if the implementation plays with a standard deck or a multi-deck shoe? If so, how many decks at each venue?
- Am I imagining things or does it seem like if you and the dealer tie, but you have a soft score (ace as 11), the dealer wins? Sometimes the game moves too quickly for me to clearly see the cards from my couch, so I'm not sure if this is the case or I'm miscounting as the cards flip across the screen -- especially as the dealer plays. :)

Comment: Can't answer the entire question, but whenever luck in any way modifies your game, you get a "You're feeling lucky!" notification.

Comment: @Arda: Thanks; I was wondering about that one. I've gotten it quite a few times in blackjack. And here I thought I just had a system!

Comment: @alexander: How is this a possible duplicate of the rules of a completely different game?

Comment: my mistake, consider it retracted

Comment: @alexander: No problem. A little while after commenting, I noticed that the `caravan` tag was mistakenly applied to the post by another user. I then proceeded to fix that. :)

Comment: At least Gomorrah appears to be using a multi-deck shoe: Just saw three black 2s (two spades, one club) on the table at one time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Luck**: I haven't found any official confirmation of exactly what the percentages are for the influence of Luck, but I've the standard advice for high (9 or 10) Luck builds at Blackjack is to basically always hit at 18 or below, always stand on a 19 or 20, Split 16's and double down on 11's, and you will always come out very far ahead. Based on anecdotal information, it seems as though the impact of luck may be at least somewhat exponential, as I can't say I've had that level of success running with 5, 6, or 7 (the highest I've taken a character to the tables with.)

**Deck**: It's a shoe at Gomorrah at the very least, though I can't say how many decks, reshuffled for every hand. The main thing to keep in mind is that the odds of a 10 are *extremely* high when it's just you and the dealer.

**Push**: You're imagining things. In the event of a Push, you'll get your bet back, but you won't win any additional caps. That said, each Casino *does* have it's own house rules. At Gomorrah, the Dealer is *required* to hit on a soft 17. At Ultra-Luxe and The Tops, the dealer will always stand on a 17.

Comment: Are we sure about the single deck? Everything else makes sense -- but I know I've seen duplicate cards on the table.

Comment: I've never seen a dupe myself. If you have, of course that'd contradict me, and I'm possibly wrong on that front. I'd love to see if that's the case. It could be another variation by casino.

Comment: Just got dealt 2 Aces of Spades at Gomorrah. Answer updated to reflect.

Comment: The question is of course assuming there *are* decks - as a programmer, if I didn't have to worry about no-duplicates, I would just randomly choose one of the 52 cards for every card dealt... that would be *much* easier than having to deal with actually shuffling and dealing cards.

Comment: Very true -  especially when you're playing fast and loose with probability to allow a 'luck' score to influence things...

Comment: I've definitely had the dupes at Gomorrah, and I think maybe at the Tops? I haven't played enough at the Atomic Wrangler or Ultra-Luxe, as they seem to be weighted much further in the dealer's direction ... (I broke the banks at both Gomorrah and the Tops -- had to regain my wealth after buying 5 implants!)

Comment: Hmmm.  They have to hit a 17?? Better odds than real life :D

Comment: @Mechko: Only at Gomorrah, and only on a Soft 17 (i.e. a 17 where an Ace is counted as 11 - 6+Ace for instance.)

Comment: I recall hearing that the Fallout team consisted of `specifically` a former gambling software developer, who  developed poker/blackjack/slot software before joining the team.

Comment: The dealer must also hit a soft 17 at Vikki & Vance, and a multi-deck shoe is in place there as well (just got a pair of 5s of hearts).

Comment: Doubling down on 10's works pretty well as well. I'll even double down on 12's and it throws me 9's like nobody's business.