# How much does luck affect the various games of chance in Fallout:New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Does anyone know how luck affects the 3 casino games ( slots , BlackJack, roulette) in Fallout:NV?  Does luck play a bigger role in one of the games more then the others?  Is there some breakover point as far as luck goes that makes it very easy to win at any of the games?

Comment: I believe slot machines are covered in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11662/what-are-the-slot-machine-odds-in-new-vegas) and Blackjack in [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9744/what-affects-blackjack-gameplay-in-fallout-new-vegas).

Answer (score 3):

The exact effects are not known, as far as I know. But the effects of luck are very noticable. If you're playing with high luck, like 8-10, it is very easy to win at any game.

As there are relatively low limits until you're expelled from the casino, probably the best game to play is the slot machines. Just play until you hit a jackpot and you'll go far above the limit and have more money than you can reasonably spend.

Comment: Apart from Ultra-Luxe. It doesn't have any slot machines so I recommend playing black jack,and just betting max and playing safe. You could play roulette but you will be there a while though.

Answer (score 3):

Blackjack with LCK of 7 is fairly easy if you know how to play. The luck kicks in occasionally, but nowhere near enough to really turn the tide.  With luck of 8 and up the 'you're feeling lucky' messages show up a lot more often and the game becomes rather silly.

Comment: +1: With 9/10 luck, if you play "sane" (hit on everything less than 15, hold on 16+) you'll win 2/3rds of your games without a problem. If you double down whenever you have 11 showing, it's like 90%